# Golang - Mapping JSON using reflect and recursion

Tags: json, recursion, go, mapping, go-reflect

I am trying to map a json data into `map[string]interface{}` using reflect and recursion . The function works like expected but it is not mapping all the value when it comes to nested json.

I have this following json structure:

```
{
  "r_id" : "123456",
  "title" : "brand new restarant with changed name",
  "address": {
      "city": {
        "id": "25",
        "name": "Dhaka"
      },
      "postal":"1213"
  },
  "description" : "here are some new desciption ..."
}
```

I am trying to map this into string for field and interface for value where the string for field if it is a nested will be joined with a dot `.`. for example mapping `title` is `map[title:brand new restarant with changed name]` but for city `name` and `id` it will be `map[address.city.id:25 address.city.name:Dhaka]`

I wrote [this script](https://gist.github.com/sh0umik/8e11b98ca5287ac8a6e0a0b35f3ea74a).

My goal is to get `key` and `value` in a map where key for nested json will be a string like `parent.child.child.child` which is a `json path` and the value will be the value of the last child

Final output should be like this: `map[address.city.id:25 address.city.name:Dhaka address.postal:1213 r_id:123456 title:brand new restarant with changed name descripton:here are some new desciption ...]` but it prints `map[address.city.id:25 address.city.name:Dhaka r_id:123456 title:brand new restarant with changed name]` But not all string field like `description` and `state` of address

I guess I need to sort the type then run the recursive function?

Comment: not sure why you're doing that, but you can pass a `map[string]interface{}` directly to Unmarshal()

Comment: updated the question with goal however simply i want to get the json path as key for nested json so that i could represent key/path = address.city.name and value = 25

Comment: https://github.com/buger/jsonparser uses paths to access JSON values without unmarshalling. You may be able look at its source for ideas.

Comment: @Nadh if jsonparser uses path then i need to generate the path from json thats the goal